# Why does respond of ajax returns always the json's name

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have this ajax function

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '?ajax=1',
    data: { 
        checkEmail : { 'email' : $(this).val() }
    },
    success:function(data){
    }
})
```

Can anybody tell me why does it always return the 'checkEmail' name? Like in the response it would give : 'checkEmailThis email has already been registered.' Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us the code that creates the response?

Answer (score 0):

Because data syntax should be like this:

```
 data: { key1: "value1", key2: "value2" }
```

See some examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Nope, it is not because of that.

Comment: Check also @Haroldo Torres's answer!

Comment: @LachezarRaychev: did you tested it? can you tell me what is `checkEmail` is it a key? then where is the value? is it inside `{ 'email' ..}` which is not correct?! why not just test correct answer before claiming!

Comment: Because even i i do it like this data{email : 'value'} it still return email in the response. Because i already tested it, because checkEmail : { 'email' : $(this).val() } is totally correct way to send ajax array. And yes checkEmail is a unique key with witch i get mu JSON in the $_POST because i may have another ajax with the same field 'email1' and i may get mixed up, this way i get always the JSON i need.

Comment: @LachezarRaychev Chances are the problem is in the script that you are using to process the post. As mentioned above can you show the code that is processing the post/returning the response?

Comment: Never mind... i found it. Ofc it was the the controller that filters the post, 10x . How can i delete this question at all ? :)